# Ecto put_assoc changeset is correct, but Repo.update gives StaleEntryError exception

Tags: elixir, ecto, changeset

I am trying to update some data in the mysql table. I am using Ecto to perform database operations.

The User table has an association with `ItemsPurchased`, the `has_many` association and `belongs_to` are as below:

```
schema "sales_orders" do
    field(:total_bill, :float)
    field(:quantity, :integer)

    field :sales_order_id, :integer
    has_many :items_purchased, Orders.ItemsPurchased, on_replace: :delete
    timestamps()
end


 schema "items_purchased" do
    field :item_id, :string
    field :product, :string
    field :description, :string
    field :picture, :string
    field :quantity, :integer
    field :required_total_bill, :decimal

    belongs_to(:sales_order, Orders.SalesOrder)

    timestamps()
  end

  schema "sales_orders" do
    field(:quantity, :integer)
    field(:so_date, :utc_datetime)

    field :sales_order_id, :integer
    has_many :sales_order_line_items, 
    Orders.SalesOrderLineItem, on_replace: :delete
    timestamps()
  end
```

The problem here is, when I am trying to update items_purchased, the ecto changeset inserts blank data. The changeset is below:

```
Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(inserted_so, :items_purchased, items_purchased)          
#Ecto.Changeset<
  action: nil,
  changes: %{
    total_bill: 300.0,
    items_purchased: [
      #Ecto.Changeset<action: :replace, changes: %{}, errors: [],
       data: #Orders.ItemsPurchased<>, valid?: true>,
      #Ecto.Changeset<
        action: :insert,
        changes: %{
          "description" => "white",
          "item_id" => "88-1",
          "product" => "tee",
          "quantity" => 50, 
          "required_total_bill" => "500"
        },
        errors: [],
        data: #Orders.ItemsPurchased<>,
        valid?: true
      >
    ]
  },
  errors: [],
  data: #Orders.SalesOrder<>,
  valid?: true
>
```

The output of Repo.update is with put_assoc is:

```
** (Ecto.StaleEntryError) attempted to delete a stale struct:
```

Can anyone let me know what is going wrong in this?

Thanks,
S

Comment: Ecto is trying to remove the old one before adding the new one (due to the on_replace: :delete). The stale error is happening because the entry was already removed from the database. Can you be calling anything between Repo.update and put_assoc that would delete the entry?

Comment: The way I am updating both the tables is like this :

#update sales_order table
sales_order_changeset = sales_order |> SalesOrder.changeset(updated_attrs) |> Repo.update

#update items_purchased table
Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(sales_order_changeset, :items_purchased, new_items_purchased)
      |> Repo.update!()

Comment: I solved this issue using cast_assoc instead of put_assoc